# jQuery UI: Two semicolons after logical expression with function wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I was looking at some jQuery UI code, a found a weird behavior there:

```
jQuery.ui||(function(a){ /*... */ })(jQuery);;
```

The logical OR is clear for me, the function wrapper (still searching the correct name for it), too, but why two semicolons?

Thanks in advance

Vincent

**EDIT:** Just found a another weird thing: In the [version on google apis](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js) is only one semicolon. But when you create your on build on http://jqueryui.com/download, there are two semicolons.

Comment: Probably a build error. Something that gets omitted between the two semicolons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking it down:

```
// make sure that any previous statements are properly closed
// this is handy when concatenating files, for example
; 
// Call the jQuery.ui object, or, if it does not exist, create it
jQuery.ui || (function($) {
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955767/what-does-it-do-jquery-ui-function)

Answer (score 0):

Typo? I cannot think of any valid reason.

Answer (score 0):

That must either be a bug or a misunderstanding. Two consecutive semicolons do not make sense.