# What's two ";" mean in javascript

Tags: javascript

When i read javascript file it has tow ";" sometimes,like:

```
(function($, undefined) {


;;

var defaults = {

    ..........
```

what that meaning?

Comment: It doesn't mean anything special. It's just an empty statement.

Comment: It means the developer had too much coffee that morning.

Comment: Empty statement: http://es5.github.io/#x12.3

Comment: Not actually an answer (because it's already been answered) but sometimes you'll see ;(function($, undefined) { ...   and that is done on purpose to close other previously loaded files (possibly) bad javascript before yours.

Comment: Sometimes it means breaking it down. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955767/what-does-it-do-jquery-ui-function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's just a null statement (known as [an "empty statement" by the ECMAScript standard](http://es5.github.io/#x12.3)). This works as well:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;alert('lots of semicolons');;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

It doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Not that it matters, but ECMAScript calls it an "empty statement". http://es5.github.io/#x12.3

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't mean anything special. The second semicolon is just an empty statement and you could safely remove it if you wanted.

Comment: Isn't the first semicolon an empty statement as well?

Comment: @FelixKling: In this example, yes. However, if the preceding lines were different that might not have been the case.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a typo. It is not necessary.

Here is a link to semicolons in JavaScript that you might find helpful.

http://www.codecademy.com/blog/78-your-guide-to-semicolons-in-javascript